# SWIFT ADMOB : Failed to load: Request Error: No ad to show

Tags: ios, swift, admob, rewardedvideoad

I'm actually developing an iOS app with AdMob Reward in Swift and when I try to build my app with the simulator (iPhone 6, 6s, 7, 8...and so on), ads works and I also have this message:

> Reward based video ad is received.

But (because there is always a but) when I build my app on my own device (iPhone 6)  that doesn't work and I have this error message : 
"Reward based video ad failed to load: Request Error: No ad to show."
This is my code (Obviously I changed Ad Id by the example given in the "Get Started with Reward Ad Mob" but in my app, I use my Ad ID). This the sample ID I choose for the example: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313

```
let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313"];
    rewardBasedVideo = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
    rewardBasedVideo?.delegate = self
    if rewardBasedVideo?.isReady == false {
        rewardBasedVideo?.load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
        adRequestInProgress = true
    }
```

And Also

```
//ADMOB
// MARK: GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate implementation
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    adRequestInProgress = false
    print("Reward based video ad failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    adRequestInProgress = false
    print("Reward based video ad is received.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Opened reward based video ad.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Reward based video ad started playing.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Reward based video ad is closed.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Reward based video ad will leave application.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    print("Reward received with currency: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")
}
//ADMOB!
```

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44481175/8334818

Answer (score 0):

First you should see your logs to get the identifier of your real device

Then fix that line:

```
request.testDevices = [...]
```

Replace the ... With the simulator as you did and the if of your real device
You then could see a test ad
You used your **ad unit id** instead using your **device id**

Comment: Hi, thanks to your response, so if I understand I did this " request.testDevices = [ "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313"];" ? Because if it onl that, that doesn't work too...

Comment: REMOVE the ad unit of from there. testDevices defines which devices load TEST ads that always shows even when no ad to show!! Look at runtime log (when debugging on a real device) you should see something like: "use the id .......... To get test ads for that device", TAKE the id and use it in the array, KEEP the simulator identifier in the array too'

Comment: I don't understand sorry could you give me an example please, thanks

Comment: Yes but in a few hours from now

Comment: Best example https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#enable_test_devices

Comment: I saw it and I did exactly the same thing but with different ID, and when I try with "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" that doesn't work too...

Comment: I guess your ad is ok, you just need to see test ad to be sure