# Admob: Getting 65k request but only 2.75k were fulfilled

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads, smartbanner

this might be the possible the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3). On PlayStore I selected no ads and on last updated, I implemented ads and forgot to update that on distribution. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3#41991172) but didn't get any success. Every morning ads are visible but after some time they are not visible. While debugging I got this error response from onAdFailedToLoad

```
Failed to load ad: 3
```

I am using the banner and interstitial ads. Yesterday total request was 81k but only fulfilled 3.3k. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ad meditation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479174/admob-ads-not-showing-swift/44481175#44481175

Comment: Does it will solve the issue? Because ads are working on my other apps but on this one. I created another app in AdMob for this one and that is also showing the same. No ads!

Comment: since you are facing fill rate issue.. AdMob Mediation helps maximize your fill rate and increase your monetization by sending ad requests to multiple networks to ensure you find the best available network to serve ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible cause:

1. *NO FILL - admob decided so (tarrgetting, no inventory, cdn failure , maintenance)
2. NO FILL - too high CPM/CPK
3. *NO FILL - CROSS ORIGIN EXECUTION BLOCKING
4. NO FILL - EXCEPTIONS in THREADS that doesn't outputs to logs
5. **NO FILL - POOR CONNECTION
6. *NO FILL - BANNED IP / SUBNET
7. NO FILL - TO MANY SHORT REPEATLY REQUESTS FROM ONE CLIENT

set debug flag  and verbose logs to exclude...

> Hi thanks for reply, what is CROSS ORIGIN EXECUTION BLOCKING? – Harish Kamboj 57 secs ago

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md

> I didn't get some time they work and some they not is there any way to fix that? – Harish Kamboj 23 secs ago

for:

ad 1,3,6/ * - NO YOU CANT FIX IT

ad 2/ lower or disable minimum CPK/CPA/CPM etc

ad 4/ try debug against thrown exceptions

ad 5/  ** - PARTIAL MAYBE -> refacor code for long waiters (synchronization)

ad 7/ monit requests from client

> Thanks @ceph3us - Harish Kamboj 39 secs ago

from personall experience - Admob has some problems with filling from about 2 months... maybe the cause is a high load or advertisers escape.. best ask at source :)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, what is CROSS ORIGIN EXECUTION BLOCKING?

Comment: I didn't get some time they work and some they not is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @HarishKamboj if the answers fits your needs pleas upvoe and accept :) thanx